# i have facing the issue in the Elementor Page builder

Tags: wordpress, elementor

The mail widget in elementor pro not working. I have installed the mail sent testing plugins, mail send but not received...

I have tried many others plugins but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure SMTP to be able to send emails. Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/ Configure the settings, and you should be able to send emails.